Does the The Myth of Sisyphus address suicide as a function of physical suffering?
Reading the existentialists back in my college literature classes, The Myth of Sisyphus is one that, for some reason, was never assigned as required reading which I’ve currently picked up and have begun tackling. Because I have a friend who suffers greatly from CFS leaks (Cerebrospinal fluid) and has had numerous surgeries and procedures, he has entertained the ideation of ending his life and hence, my interest in Camus. I understand from the books’s preface that, “even if one does not believe in G-d, suicide is not legitimate.” I get that, but I’m wondering if the book addresses suicide relative to physical suffering.

See e.g. Robert Zaretsky, A Life Worth Living: Albert Camus and the Quest for Meaning (Belknap Press, 2013), Prologue: "The experience of suffering is central to the life and work of a moralist. [...] The ancient Greeks, the deep source of Camus’ inspiration, had no doubts: suffering had its advantages. [...] M.Nussbaum’s remark on the educative role of suffering in Greek tragedy also applies in spades to Camus:  1/2

'There is a kind of knowing that works by suffering because suffering is the appropriate acknowledgement of the way human life, in these cases, is.' [The Fragility of Goodness (1986), p,45.]" 2/2

Thank you Mauro for these additional resources — especially the work by Nussbaum. That, along with the works of Jung, provide much depth of insight though, on a personal note, it's one thing to find yourself hanging by a thread emotionally and physically where no amount of academia can relieve the intensity of affliction. Nevertheless, thank you!

You are welcome! But Camus' existentialism (Sisyphus etc) is aimed at showing that, despite its absurdity and the "rationality " of suicide, life is worth to be lived.

I don't think Camus is arguing that suicide is never legitimate. The way I read him, he only argues that it's not a "solution" to the absurdity of life - an absurdity that we're all dealing with simply because we're mortal, given that there are no sources of value beyond actually being alive. This is also not so much an argument as a deliberately absurd expression of defiance against "the absurd". If someone can recognize themselves in that, that's fine - it was valuable for me when I was young - but in some cases, I believe, it may be better to accept that there is always a way out.

So, imo, Camus seriously underestimates the reality of human physical suffering in The Myth. He does not really engage with it. Emile Cioran -- a much more tortured, raw existentialist (also literally: he did suffer from chronic pain and insomnia) -- addresses this much more directly -- and plainly. Suffering is -- in the end -- not enobling. It can be insane and totally immoral to ask for some absurd defiance...

If you're looking for an exploration on the ethics of suicide, you're in the wrong place. The short of it is that what the majority of the book really addresses is "philosophical suicide" which at the elementary level is simply giving up on life and critical thinking. This book is not about euthanasia and assisted-suicide. It's about dealing with all of the useless rationalizations and utter absurdities of being born only to die. And ultimately, Camus, a man full of life, rejects it. From the WP article The Myth of Sisyphus:

For Camus, who sets out to take the absurd seriously and follow it to its final conclusions, these "leaps" cannot convince. Taking the absurd seriously means acknowledging the contradiction between the desire of human reason and the unreasonable world. Suicide, then, also must be rejected: without man, the absurd cannot exist. The contradiction must be lived; reason and its limits must be acknowledged, without false hope. However, the absurd can never be permanently accepted: it requires constant confrontation, constant revolt. (emphasis mine)


I like your comment regarding "critical thinking" which is an invaluable insight into Camus' thought processes.

On page 49 he says: "For the [absurd mind] the world is neither so rational nor so irrational. It is unreasonable and only that." As I read Camus, there is an irony in trying to project the rationality of the rational animal on the unreasonable world... that is, a world that largely escapes demonstrating reasonableness. Death, poverty, suffering, inequity, iniquity. None of these is a product of reasonable forces. They simply are, and one simply must accept it. In Camus's The Plague, he attempts to show the arbitrary nature of nature itself, and the falsity of ideologies that "explain" it.

I may have to revisit that work by Camus which I know I read back in college. Thanks!

I do not remember that Camus argues for suicide because of bodily pain.
Instead, Camus argues to endure the clash between the human need for clarity and rational understanding on one hand, and the non-rational world which remains silent. He names this clash "absurd".
The book is a short classic. I recommend to read it yourself.

Thank you Jo and I'm currently in the process of reading it. I'll keep your thoughts in mind as I read.
